# breaking of output into new lines

Tags: shell-script

I created a script `./abc`.

I want to break the ouput into new lines.

mycode:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="$1"

echo -n "size of file:"
du -hba $dir | sort -n -r | tail -1
```

my output is:

```
size of files: 20kb /path/to/sport
```

I want the output as:

```
size of files: 20kb
         /path/to/sport
```

Comment: Please would you show the part of the code that generates this.

Comment: @roaima I edited my question. could you please check my code.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider something like this:

```
du="$(du -hba "$dir" | sort -n -r | tail -1)"
printf "size of file: %s\n\t%s\n" "${du/$'\t'*}" "${du#*$'\t'}"
```

The `du` variable takes the result of your search. It is then split into two tab-separated parts for the `printf` statement, with each of the parts interpolated into the format string with `%s`.

This construct should handle filenames containing newlines, tabs, and other unusual characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
./abc | sed 's/files: /files: \n/'
```

I tried on my system with `echo` command:

```
$ echo "size of files: 20kb /path/to/sport" | sed 's/files: /files: \n\t/'
size of files:
        20kb /path/to/sport
```

Comment: could you please check my expected output once. It has to be display as : size of files: 20kb